# Appium Inspector not running giving me error 'An unknown server-side "

Tags: appium, appium-inspector

I am getting the below error when fill all the required details and my appium inspector is not working.

Error
Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: You must include a platformName capability
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80e6r.png)

I tried it again to write again , with reactive the server and inspector but didn't work anything for me.
Please provide me solution so i can start the appium.

Answer (score 1):

Use this "platformName": "Android"

instead of appium:PlatformName.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).